# When does kaddish for a parent end in a leap year?

Tags: kaddish

A parent died on the second of Cheshvan 5776 which is a leap year.  When does kaddish end, 11 months later or one month before a full year?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  I've made an edit to clarify your question; please check that I haven't misunderstood.  You can [edit] further.  Thanks.